# Vue.js, Vuex; component view not reacting when data in the Vuex store is mutated (with mysterious exception)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

This is my first foray into using Vuex, and I'm baffled by a problem relating to a searchResults array, managed in the $store, specifically why a SearchResults view component doesn't seem to be reacting when the store is mutated.

I have a search form component which, when submitted, invokes a search function (mixin), dispatches an action which updates the searchResults array in the store, and then loads ViewSearchResults.vue, where the search results are displayed - and this is working.

Now, ViewSearchResults.vue also includes the search form component, and when a subsequent search is run, again the search function runs successfully, the store is updated accordingly, however ViewSearchResults.vue is not reacting to the change in the store, e.g., update lifecycle doesn't fire, so the new search results are unavailable

... and then in my debugging journey I discovered that by adding a reference to the store in the template - e.g., `{{ this.$store.state.searchResults.length }}`, the view updates, the new data is available, and any subsequent searches successfully update the view.

None of my experience with Vue.js so far explains this. Can someone please shed some light on this, and how I can realize the desired results without polluting my markup?.

Many thanks in advance.

relevant excerpt of my search mixin:

```js
export default {
    created: function() {},
    methods: {
        doSearch: function(term) {
            const searchTerm = term.toLowerCase();
            this.$store.dispatch("setSearchTerm", term);
            let searchResults = [];
            // SNIP: search (iterate) a bunch of .json data ...
            searchResults.push(searchResult); // searchResults array CONFIRMED √
            this.$store.dispatch("setSearchResults", searchResults);
        }
    }
}
```

relevant excerpt of the store:

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
    strict: true,
    state: {
        searchTerm: "",
        searchResults: [],
    },
    mutations: {
        setSearchTerm(state, payload) {
            state.searchTerm = payload;
        },
        setSearchResults(state, payload) {
            console.log(payload); // √ confirmed: updated array is there
            state.searchResults = payload;
            console.log(state.searchResults); // √ confirmed: updated array is there
        }
    },
    getters: {
    },
    actions: {
        // dispatched in the search mixin
        setSearchTerm(context, payload){
            context.commit("setSearchTerm", payload);
        },
        setSearchResults(context, payload) {
            context.commit("setSearchResults", payload);
        }
    },
    modules: {
    }
})
```

... and ViewSearchResults.vue (relevant excerpts):

```html
// IF I LEAVE THIS IN, BOB'S YOUR UNCLE ... WITHOUT IT, THE VIEW DOESN'T REACT
<div style="display: none;">this.$store.state.searchResults: {{ this.$store.state.searchResults.length }}</div>

<ul class="search-results">
    <li v-for="(imgObj, ix) in searchResults" :key="ix">
        <img :src="require('@/assets/img/collections/' + imgObj.path + '/' + imgObj.data + '/' + imgObj.imgFile)" alt="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```js
export default {
    components: {
        // 'app-search' occurs elswhere in the app, but when submitted, loads this ViewSearchResults, search component still present
        'app-search': SearchForm
    },
    props: {
    },
    data() {
        return {
            searchTerm: "",
            searchResults: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        // only becuz refresh
        if (!this.searchTerm) {
            this.searchTerm = this.$route.params.searchTerm;
        }
        console.log(this.$store.state.searchResults.length); // 0 if refreshed, ERGO:
        this.$store.state.searchResults.length ? this.searchResults = this.$store.state.searchResults : this.searchResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchResults"));
        console.log(this.searchResults); // searchResults √
    },
    updated: function() {
        // ?!?!?! WHY DOES THIS FIRE ONLY IF I LEAVE THE REFERENCE TO THE STORE IN THE TEMPLATE? {{ this.$store.state.searchResults.length }}
        this.$store.state.searchTerm ? this.searchTerm = this.$store.state.searchTerm : this.searchTerm = localStorage.getItem("searchTerm");
        this.$store.state.searchResults.length ? this.searchResults = this.$store.state.searchResults : this.searchResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("searchResults"));
    },
    computed: {
    },
    mounted: function() {},
    mixins: [ Search ]
}
```

Many thanks again for any insight.

Whiskey T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got nothing updating in your component so it won't need to execute the `update` hook.

It seems you actually want your component to be driven by the values in the store.

I would set it up as [recommended in the Vuex guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components)

```js
computed: {
  searchResults () {
    return this.$store.state.searchResults
  }
},
created () {
  this.doSearch(this.$route.params.searchTerm)
}
```

You could also use the [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper) if you wanted.

```js
computed: mapState(['searchResults']),
```

---

The part where you load data from localstorage should be done in your store's state initialiser, ie

```js
let initialSearchResults
try {
  initialSearchResults = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('searchResults'))
} catch (e) {
  console.warn('Could not parse saved search results')
  initialSearchResults = []
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    searchTerm: "",
    searchResults: initialSearchResults
  },
```

Comment: Thank you Phil! Don't know how I missed this, basic Vuex no doubt.

I added LocalStorage only because I was losing searchResults & the .json data - both from the store - when refreshing the search results view. My goal is to ensure the search term (a route param), search results, etc. survive a refresh, browser 'back' & 'forward', etc., and that the search function doesn't lose track of the .json data in the store. cheers, Whiskey T.